# interpretation baseline corrected ANCOVA

Tags: interpretation, ancova, predictor

I hope you can help me with some statistic 'problem', or maybe check is more accurate =].

I have data on an experiment with a 2 by 3 design, with session(first/second) and medication(a/b/c) as factors. The outcome measurement is a visual analogue scale, measuring emotion. Medication is only given after the first session.

My problem is that the medication groups differ on the VAS at the first session and age, and therefore complicate the interpretation of the effect of medication. These differences are trend significant. My solution would be to use an ANCOVA with:

- DV : VAS score during second session
- Fixed factor: medication
- Covariates: VAS score during first session and Age

My results show a significant interaction between session and medication, corrected for first session differences in VAS and age. The bonferroni corrected pairwise comparisons suggests that medication a and b have different effects on the VAS, but neither differs from c (placebo). This may be caused by a lack of power, because n=12 in all three medication groups.

Would you consider this a sound analysis method and interpretation?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a reasonable analysis and interpretation.  A couple of thoughts: 
-Since drug A and B differ from each other but not placebo, I assume one increases VAS score and the other decreases it.  Does that make sense to you based on the hypothesized drug effect?
-I agree that N of 12/ group may be low.  Check the variability and the effect you were seeking.
-Does it makes sense that age should affect the relationship between medication and VAS?  Was it significant in the model?  If not, you may want to consider dropping that variable from the model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

1. yes, the differential effect of A & B make sense

2. What do you mean with 'check variability and the effect you were seeking?'

3. Age does not have a significant impact on the relationship between medication, so yes i guess I could drop that!

Comment: In re: 'check variability and the effect you were seeking' I just meant that if you did a power analysis beforehand, you could see if your assumptions were correct in terms of variability and treatment effect.  If you didn't do a prior power analysis and you have a sense of what a meaningful change on the VAS would be, you can use your information about the VAS variability to know how large a study would need to be to detect a treatment effect of that size.